# Homepage Ajax/Google Maps - Server overhead

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-maps

Adding a Google Map plugin to our homepage, which updates a single marker dynamically whenever there is a new product search on our site (which we read from our database).  So, "has there been a new search via our site? If yes, reposition the marker based on the new search's coords".

Currently every "n" seconds (haven't settled on a seconds value yet) an Ajax call is made (using SetInterval) to determine if there has been a new search, and if there has it returns a small JSON response.  The script run via the Ajax call is a PHP script, which queries the database for the last row in our searches table (order by desc limit 1).

So, my question is (not being a sysadmin), could this setup put an undesirable strain on our server?  Should i incorporate a timeout session, or something, which turns off the Ajax call after 100 goes, or after 15 mins (i mean, who sits for 15 mins looking at markers dynamically generate on a Google map?!).

Our homepage only receives roughly 200 visits a day.

Answer (score 0):

As you have you given the statistics that your website gets 200 visits per day and that your server is a spitting JSON that you have to extract and display it on the UI, It is a normal practice to have a set up like this one. You can rather ping the server data using AJAX in every 5 sec to get more precise data but it wont cause any performance issue at this level.

Please be sure that you dont have servers that are separated geographically else you have to use some other synchronization mechanism to track users location based on there search.

For AJAX JQuery implementation details please see the following [page](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

For project implementation as a tutorial please visit this [tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/ajax/).